# jQuery Animated Scroll Stops Too Early

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, user-interface, scroll

I am running this guy on an ng-click of a button

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#displayOne").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Depending on how far down the page I am when I click the button it stops way too early, is there a different way to get the correct scroll position no matter where displayOne is?

Comment: did you wail until the document is loaded ? `$(document).ready(function(){/*your code*/})`

Comment: It's on an ng-click, no matter how long I wait it still goes short on certain parts of the page.